# Why does my first value printed in Bid History return as undefined but each one after returns correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

This was a homework assignment that has already been turned in. I am trying to understand why the first submit returns a undefined value in the time spot, but when it is done again it populates correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!--
```

Author: Anthony Weed
   Date:  02/16/2015

Filename:         auction.htm
   Supporting files: ACMlogo.jpg, styles.css

```
-->

<head>  <title>Auction Log</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"
<title>Auction Log</title>
<script>
var bids = [];
var bidders = [];
var bidTime = [];
var nowTime = new Date();

function updateBid() {
    var bidHistory = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < bids.length; i++) {
        bidHistory += bidTime[i] + bids[i] + "( " + bidders[i] + " )" ;
    }
    var grr = bids[0];
    document.bidForm.bidList.value = bidHistory;
    document.bidForm.highBid.value = grr;
    document.bidForm.bidId.value = "";
    document.bidForm.bidAmount.value = "";
}

function addBid() {
    var id_elem = document.getElementById('bidId');
    var idval = id_elem.value;
    bidders.unshift(idval);

    console.log(idval);
    var amt_elem = document.getElementById('bidAmount');
    var amtval = amt_elem.value;
    bids.unshift(amtval);
    updateBid();

    var nowTime = new Date();
    var hours = nowTime.getHours();
    var minutes = nowTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = nowTime.getSeconds();
    var textTime = "["+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "]";
    bidTime.unshift(textTime);
}

function removeBid() {
    bids.shift();
    bidders.shift();
    bidTime.shift();
    updateBid();
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <form name="bidForm" id="bidForm">
    <div id="head">
      <p> <a href="#">Home</a>  <a href="#">Auctions</a>
        <a href="#">Features</a>  <a href="#">Schedule</a>
        <a href="#">Contacts</a>

      </p>
      <img src="ACMlogo.jpg" alt="ACM Silent Auction" />
    </div>
    <div id="intro">
      <h1>Silent Auction</h1>

      <h2>TWU ACM </h2>

      <table id="summarytable" border="2">
        <tr>
          <th>Item #21</th>
          <td>Skyfall (DVD)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Current High Bid</th>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="highBid" name="highBid" value="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Bidding Ends</th>
          <td>15:00PM</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="newbidtable" border="2">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" id="newtitle">Enter New Bid</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Bidder ID</th>
          <td>
            <input id="bidId" name="bidId" type ="text" value=""/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Bid Amount</th>
          <td>
            <input id="bidAmount" name="bidAmount" type="text" value="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="buttons" colspan="2">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick='addBid()'/>
            <input type="button" value="Remove Last Bid" onClick='removeBid()'/>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="bidHistory">
      <h1>Bid History</h1>

      <p>
        <textarea id="bidList" name="bidList"></textarea>
      </p>
    </div> <address>
      TWU &#183;
      MCL 307 &#183;
      Denton, TX 76204
    </address>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the addbid function, you call updatebid() and then process date time info and put it into the bidtime array.  When updatebid() runs for the first time, bidtime[0] has not yet been created and assigned.

Comment: after working on the code for so long and running debugging, never even noticed that it was being called before the time stuff... thy

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `updateBid()` before you add the current time to `bidTime`. So `bidTime` has one less element than `bids`. When you try to access the missing element, you get `undefined`. Just move the call to `updateBid()` to the end of `addBid()`

```js
var bids = [];
var bidders = [];
var bidTime = [];
var nowTime = new Date();

function updateBid() {
    var bidHistory = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < bids.length; i++) {
        bidHistory += bidTime[i] + bids[i] + "( " + bidders[i] + " )";
    }
    var grr = bids[0];
    document.bidForm.bidList.value = bidHistory;
    document.bidForm.highBid.value = grr;
    document.bidForm.bidId.value = "";
    document.bidForm.bidAmount.value = "";
}

function addBid() {
    var id_elem = document.getElementById('bidId');
    var idval = id_elem.value;
    bidders.unshift(idval);

    console.log(idval);
    var amt_elem = document.getElementById('bidAmount');
    var amtval = amt_elem.value;
    bids.unshift(amtval);

    var nowTime = new Date();
    var hours = nowTime.getHours();
    var minutes = nowTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = nowTime.getSeconds();
    var textTime = "[" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "]";
    bidTime.unshift(textTime);
    updateBid();
}

function removeBid() {
    bids.shift();
    bidders.shift();
    bidTime.shift();
    updateBid();
}
```

```html
<form name="bidForm" id="bidForm">
    <div id="head">
        <p> <a href="#">Home</a>  <a href="#">Auctions</a>
 <a href="#">Features</a>  <a href="#">Schedule</a>
 <a href="#">Contacts</a>

        </p>
        <img src="ACMlogo.jpg" alt="ACM Silent Auction" />
    </div>
    <div id="intro">
         <h1>Silent Auction</h1>

         <h2>TWU ACM </h2>

        <table id="summarytable" border="2">
            <tr>
                <th>Item #21</th>
                <td>Skyfall (DVD)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Current High Bid</th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="highBid" name="highBid" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Bidding Ends</th>
                <td>15:00PM</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="newbidtable" border="2">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" id="newtitle">Enter New Bid</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Bidder ID</th>
                <td>
                    <input id="bidId" name="bidId" type="text" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Bid Amount</th>
                <td>
                    <input id="bidAmount" name="bidAmount" type="text" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th id="buttons" colspan="2">
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick='addBid()' />
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Last Bid" onClick='removeBid()' />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="bidHistory">
         <h1>Bid History</h1>

        <p>
            <textarea id="bidList" name="bidList"></textarea>
        </p>
    </div> <address>
      TWU &#183;
      MCL 307 &#183;
      Denton, TX 76204
    </address>

</form>
```

Instead of separate arrays for `bids`, `bidders`, and`bidTime`, consider using a single array of objects.

```
bidInfo.unshift({
    bid: amtval,
    bidder: idval,
    time: textTime
});
```

Comment: i wish i could have done that it would have been much easier of a task but for some reason our teach thought this method was a better way of doing it.